# Finding an angle, given various angles and lengths

Tags: geometry, triangulation

I've been slaving over this for a couple days now and I can't seem to get a resolution at all.
Can anyone solve for $\alpha$?
[image: example]

Given data is the length of the red line that isn't tangential, $\angle$ $\delta$, $\angle$L and The length of the radius of the circle.

Comment: What is the data given on this problem ?

Comment: The given data is $\partial$ and L. I probably shouldn't have used $\partial$ as a variable :S

Comment: So, the radius of the circle is not given?

Comment: I misspoke, Radius of the circle is given aswell, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the lengths and directions of two sides of the triangle, you can compute the coordinates of its right-hand vertex relative to the centre of the circle; their ratio gives you $\tan\alpha$:

$$
\alpha=\arctan\frac{r\sin\partial+d\sin(\partial-\pi+L)}{r\cos\partial+d\cos(\partial-\pi+L)}\;,
$$

where $r$ is the radius and $d$ is the length of the red line.

Comment: This solution is so utterly simple, but it baffled me for days, thank you very much!

Comment: @KorvinSzanto, the solution is clever, not so simple though!